# How to call a function daily in Wordpress & PHP without using cron?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm writing a plugin to show a Daily Quote on front-page of a WordPress site.

Basically, I want to get one random daily quote. I have a custom post type `daily_quotes`.

I'm having trouble with doing this query every day at 23:59 or 00:00.

I'm looking for a solution to do this and some example would be nice.

EDIT: I forgot to say that cron jobs aren't the option I need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run PHP Script every 5-10 minutes without cron,perl etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857741/run-php-script-every-5-10-minutes-without-cron-perl-etc)

Comment: Can you explain why cron jobs aren't the option you need? Saves us from suggesting another similar option you don't need :)

Comment: Because I have no access to web server and I won't get it. I have to do it using PHP or by some way using WordPress functions. I know it's possible because there are some plugins, but they are very old.

Comment: Have you looked at wp_cron?

Comment: I did and I didn't quite understand it. The query should get one quote, store it in variable and echo it on the front-page. When the time comes, it should run the query again, get another quote and echo it on the front-page. If you could explain to me how to do this using wp_cron, I would give it a try. :)

Comment: Then maybe you are asking the wrong question. Maybe your question should be: how you could get your cron job to work including the code where you tried to get it to work.

Comment: Afaik *something* you need to provide the daily initiation of the `daily_quotes` request. In such a situation first I would look for some free network service which can do this - directly or indirectly. Or.... see my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if `crontab` is not an option, it is not a big problem.

There is a very simple trick, put in the front of your homepage script. Pseudocode follows:

```
if (last_call_of_daily_quotes < now - 1day) {
    daily_quotes();
    last_call_of_daily_quotes = now;
}
```

So, we check on every page call if the quotes were updated last time earlier as a day. If yes, we update the quotes (and store the the current day as the time of the last change).

Where and how would you store the last quote update time? It is already your task, I suggest try to follow the WP customs as possible.